# Getting last state in useffect instead of current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call an action using a state array but I keep getting the previous value inside the action

```
 useEffect(() => {

    if (order != null && couriersPleaseData.toPostcode != 0 && packages.length > 0) {
      const _couriersPleaseData = {
        toSuburb: order.shipping_address.city,
        toPostcode: parseInt(order.shipping_address.zip),
        packages: order.tint_packages
      };

      //@ts-ignore
      setCouriersPleaseData({ ...couriersPleaseData, ..._couriersPleaseData });
      getCouriersPleaseQuote(couriersPleaseData, settings);
    }
  }, [packages]);
```

From what I believe this would run every time packages change, but I only get the previous state inside the action instead of the current state.

Edit = 
My output is -

```
fromSuburb: "Fitzroy", fromPostcode: 3065, toSuburb: "Sydney", toPostcode: 2000, packages: Array(0)}
fromPostcode: 3065
fromSuburb: "Fitzroy"
packages: []
toPostcode: 2000
toSuburb: "Sydney"
```

when I print it from getCouriersPleaseQuote

Comment: previous value of what? complete state? please also remove the code isn't directly related to your issue like `consolelogs`

Comment: the initial state, so this console log prints 0 packages to start with and as I add packages lone by one this gives me the previous state. lets say I added 2 packages then the last console log would be of 1 package. so the old state instead of the current one. I need the current state for my getCouriersPleaseQuote function.

Comment: where do you add packages

Comment: I add it once on component mount and then one by one with a form.

Comment: can u please show the definition of these two? 

      `setCouriersPleaseData({ ...couriersPleaseData, ..._couriersPleaseData });`
      `getCouriersPleaseQuote(couriersPleaseData, settings);`

Comment: Looks like you have some [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) because the callback is only passed to the effect runner when packages change, not when any of the other values change. Can you check your console to see if there are [missing dependency](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) warnings? If app is created with a recent version of create react app then you should get those when dependencies are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you've *just* set the `couriersPleaseData`, so it's *next* state value won't be available during *this* render cycle. You can use a second effect to trigger when `couriersPleaseData` updates though.

```
useEffect(() => {

  if (order != null && couriersPleaseData.toPostcode != 0 && packages.length > 0) {
    const _couriersPleaseData = {
      toSuburb: order.shipping_address.city,
      toPostcode: parseInt(order.shipping_address.zip),
      packages: order.tint_packages
    };

    //@ts-ignore
    setCouriersPleaseData({ ...couriersPleaseData, ..._couriersPleaseData });
    //getCouriersPleaseQuote(couriersPleaseData, settings); // <-- can't here, still current state value!
  }
}, [packages]);

useEffect(() => {
  getCouriersPleaseQuote(couriersPleaseData, settings)
}, [couriersPleaseData]);
```